# Memory leak issue when animating gif in UICollectionView and get crash on device but doesn't crash on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-leaks

I'm developing keyboard app and user can input gifs. Btw gifs are previewable in keyboard, It works fine with simulator and also on device, we can see gifs are animating. But it shows memory leak issue and when we continue to scroll, The app get crash in device.
I'm using FLAnimatedImage to display gif.
Here's my source code.

```
NSURL *url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[rampageGif objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] withExtension:@"gif"];
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
FLAnimatedImage *animatedImage1 = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:data1];
cell.imageView.animatedImage = animatedImage1;
```

Here's imageView decleartion.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FLAnimatedImageView *imageView;
```

Is there anybody who has experience in this area?
Any help will be appreciated.

Note: When we don't animate gif(only showing static gif image), then memory leak issue doesn't appear and app doesn't crash.

Comment: hey @David did you find any solution?

Comment: I have same issue of memory leak with gif in collectionview. any one have solution then please help us..